# Postgres table from test.csv file question

Tags: postgresql

I want to copy the csv file to the table . all of the csv file columns is mapped the table columns. But  there is a auto increment column  in the table .

for example:

test.csv file has 3 columns A ,B, C.The relative value is "city","name","sex"

```
A-------B-------C
city----name----sex
```

testtable also has 4 columns seq_no,A,B,C . seq_no is auto increment column .

copy to testtable from "test.csv" delimiter ',' csv 
it will has a error :  copy tabletst , line1 ,cloumn seq_no: "city"  .

Actually , i hope the first line will be

```
seq_no---A-------B-------C
1        city    name    sex
```

I can not change the csv and table . bcz they are common .

i insert csv data to table with postgres copy command in the shell. how to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add the columns, you want to copy into:

```sql
COPY testtable(a, b, c)
FROM "test.csv"
DELIMITER ',',
FORMAT CSV
```

The default value of column `seq_no` should now be used.

**EDIT**: Since the column names are changing and we just know their position in the table, we might fetch them dynamically from the catalog and use them later to build the `COPY` command:

```sql
SELECT a.attname
FROM pg_attribute a
INNER JOIN pg_class c ON c.oid = a.attrelid
INNER JOIN pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
WHERE c.relname = 'insertTableNameHere'
    AND n.nspname = 'insertSchemaNameHere' --probably public
    AND a.attnum > 1
ORDER BY a.attnum
```

This gives you every usually visible column (so those you see if you use `SELECT *`) in order "left to right".

Comment: yes. It is good idea. but  there is problem in my case is   there are around 100 tables named table_1 , table_2 ,table_3....table_100 . and these tables are not the same structure .   I have to write 100 times copy command. So i do not want add the specified column name in the copy command.

Comment: Different structures make things a bit more complicated.. Option 1 (not so nice, but..): alter the order of your columns, such that the three columns you got values for are the first. Option 2: Make a query to the catalog before each insert and retrieve the column names. Use them for your parameterized SQL command as well

Comment: Thank you  for your quickly reply. I am not very clear about your   Option 2. Could you give me more details ?

Comment: Thank you for your great support . I will try